# Opening bit.ly links in the application for Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, bitly, android-universal-link

You can find deep links to my own site from the Android application. In addition to these deeplinks, can I open my own application when clicking on the bit.ly/xxx URLs created with bit.ly?

The link directed to bit.ly goes to my site, but the app does not open.

If I can, can you help me on how to do it?